# Python Web application: Refresh values

Tags: python, wifi, refresh, web.py

I use a template of a python script (running on Raspberry Pi) to send sensor data (i2c) via WiFi to my PC. The problem is, the values are not static. If I start the Web application, it reads the data from the sensor only once. So, if I check the values from my PC, I can see it sent the data correctly, but they won't change.

How can I modify the script to refresh the `i2c_output` value, without starting the script over and over again?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```python
import web
import sys, os
import smbus
import math

#
# Lot of initialisation... forget that part
#

accel_xout = read_word_2c(0x3b)
accel_yout = read_word_2c(0x3d)
accel_zout = read_word_2c(0x3f)
afs_sel = read_word_2c(0x28)
LSB_afs_sel = 16384.0

accel_xout_sc = accel_xout / LSB_afs_sel
accel_yout_sc = accel_yout / LSB_afs_sel
accel_zout_sc = accel_zout / LSB_afs_sel

i2c_output = str(accel_xout_sc) + str(accel_yout_sc) + str(accel_zout_sc)


urls = ( '/','Index',
)

class Index:
  def GET(self):
    return i2c_output

if __name__=="__main__":
    app=web.application(urls,globals())
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code that retrieves the sensor data into a method and invoke that method each time the index is called.

```
def get_sensor_output():
    #
    # Lot of initialisation... forget that part
    #

    accel_xout = read_word_2c(0x3b)
    accel_yout = read_word_2c(0x3d)
    accel_zout = read_word_2c(0x3f)
    afs_sel = read_word_2c(0x28)
    LSB_afs_sel = 16384.0

    accel_xout_sc = accel_xout / LSB_afs_sel
    accel_yout_sc = accel_yout / LSB_afs_sel
    accel_zout_sc = accel_zout / LSB_afs_sel

    i2c_output = str(accel_xout_sc) + str(accel_yout_sc) + str(accel_zout_sc)

    return i2c_output

class Index:
  def GET(self):
    return get_sensor_output()
```

Note: You may want to implement some sort of cache depending on how often this get method is called. currently each call will retrieve the sensor data, which may or may not be an expensive operation that will drain the battery on your pi

Comment: First, thanks for the reply! This works fine for me =) The initialisation don't have to be inside the definition. The operation will cost some energy, but its for test runs only ;)